# How to display exact current year in yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2-basic-app

In yii2, how can we display exact current year even if the user has changed the system year.

For eg. if year is 2017 and if we change the year from system to 2018, then how should we display correct year i.e, 2017

Comment: Why would someone change the system year? What system are you reffering to? Also, what have you tried? Please show us your code.

Comment: You can't, doesn't matter what library you use, if the time on the client computer was changed, clientside code can't now what the accurate time is. You have to either make a serverside request or use an online service.

Comment: What kind of scenario are you trying to handle? If the system clock cannot be used, you'll have to implement some web service to retrieve the information from outside (either a custom web service that just returns the year or maybe some NTP client) but you won't be able to do a lot with it. It looks like too much work.

Comment: I am developing village survey system where user records the survey information. There is Year field which is non-editable textbox. Through javascript I have displayed the year in textbox where user can't change the year. But if he changes the system date, then the respective date also gets changed in the Year textbox. The year should be compulsory current year

Comment: Have the server write the year into the HTML, and always validate.

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If the user cannot choose the year there's simply no point in asking him. If you think that current year is an important piece of info for the user just display a static label generated from server—in PHP that'd be `echo date('Y');`.

If you feel that having current year changed and not getting it updated real-time in your HTML while the user is filling the survey is not acceptable, you might want to consider making your survey *shorter*.